# Verifying ExtJs tool tip with WebDriver

Tags: extjs, selenium, webdriver

Hi i have an UI application build on ExtJS4. I am able to identify the tool tip controls. But now the problem is that when i am hovering to other control for getting the tool tip the previous one is still visible which is happening while running my WebDriver test. But manually when i am trying to replicate the above issue it is not happening. Below is the HTML src for ExtJS Tool tip

```
<div id="ext-gen1561" class="x-tip-bwrap">
<div class="x-tip-ml">
<div class="x-tip-mr">
<div id="ext-gen1564" class="x-tip-mc">
<div id="ext-gen1562" class="x-tip-body" style="height: auto; width: 288px;">
<div>This is the name of an Industry Classification value. The user can supplement this information by using the Class Description field.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my java method :

```
public static String getToolTipBodyString(WebElement element)
    {
        //To do part.
        //Body : ext:qtip
        toolActionObj.hover(element);
        WebElement toolTipElement=toolActionObj.getElementByXpath(".//div[contains(@style,'visibility: visible')]//*/div[@class='x-tip-body']/div");
        String toolTipString=toolGetPropertiesObj.getText(toolTipElement);
        builder.release(element).perform();
        return toolTipString;
    }
```

The screen shot of multiple tool tips present[image: Multiple tool tips present at the same time even though i have hovered over other control.]
The above method accepts the label element on which if we hover the tool tip will appear. the method will then find out the visible tool tip control and get the text out of it and return it to testNGs assert method for assertion with the expected tool tip text. Now here the problem is that when i am running my above method for multiple controls then the older tool tips are still visible and then i am getting the older tool tip controls and not the tool tip controls of elements on which i am hovering. is this selenium webdrivers problem or ExtJS problem. how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, the hover release is not working or not performed in an appropriate  way.

As a work around try this and let me know.

```
public static String getToolTipBodyString(WebElement element)
{
    //To do part.
    //Body : ext:qtip
    toolActionObj.hover(element);
    WebElement toolTipElement=toolActionObj.getElementByXpath(".//div[contains(@style,'visibility: visible')]//*/div[@class='x-tip-body']/div");
    String toolTipString=toolGetPropertiesObj.getText(toolTipElement);
    element.click();;
    return toolTipString;
}
```

Also, try with different browsers and post us on the result.

Comment: i have tried ur solution but still the same issue in Firefox. Configuration : Webdriver :- 2.33 FF:- 22. Any other solution? TIA

Comment: @Mrunal Gosar, Can you please try with some other browser?

Comment: i have tried with IE9. It is running worse than the FireFox. with huge flickering issues. And Google Chrome is not in my scope. so it does not makes sense in checking in that browser. so now what needs to be done?